# How to fix 'min() arg is an empty sequence' python+couchdb error

Tags: python, django, couchdb

I have to do mosaic application in Python using Django and Couchdb, which are kind of new to me, for my studies. In part where I'm trying to do the mosaic, I got ValueError at 'min' function. However I run out of ideas why it is not working.

I read the couchdb docs, reach some friends who already know a little python.

```
        rgb_of_tile = list(tile.getdata())
        rgb_of_tile_list = utils.get_average_rgb_as_list(rgb_of_tile)

        returned_tiles = get_tiles(rgb_of_tile_list)

        closest = min(returned_tiles, key=lambda c: (
                (rgb_of_tile_list[0] - c['key'][0]) ** 2 +(rgb_of_tile_list[1] - c['key'][1]) ** 2 + (
                    rgb_of_tile_list[2] - c['key'][2]) ** 2))
```

Error occurs on variable 'closest', but when I looked at the error I saw that 'returned_tiles'=[ ]. Below is code for that variable. I don't really know why it is not working, as the CouchDB reference-'tiles_url' should work properly

```
       def get_tiles(rgb_of_tile_list):
         rgb_of_tile_start = [x.__sub__(10) for x in rgb_of_tile_list]
         rgb_of_tile_finish = [x.__add__(10) for x in rgb_of_tile_list]
         tiles_url = "http://images_db_user:pass@localhost:5984/images/_design/view/_view/new-view?start_key=" + str(
    rgb_of_tile_start) + "&end_key=" + str(rgb_of_tile_finish) + "&include_docs=true"
         response = requests.get(tiles_url).json()
         returned_tiles = response['rows']
         return returned_tiles
```

Comment: use your debugger to look at each step in your `get_tiles` function, especially the `tiles_url` (is it correct) and the `response`. There's no way we can help nor reproduce your issue.

Comment: Could you post the error you are receiving?

Comment: Im currently away from my pc, I got this screens, sorry for link to disc.. https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1q4LJ4r8_wTP0o48JhfzcQInNg-AlwJxe                             How to use the debugger? Sorry, its all new to me, I dont really know how to use debbuger with django.